# Swift 4: Deleting an object in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

I am trying to delete an object from my `tableView` using `commitEditingStyle`. When I delete the object and create another one with the same name, the old values come up for this object too. I don't understand what the problem is here. I think I cannot delete the object properly.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let habitContext:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        habitContext.delete(self.habitArray![indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
        self.habitArray!.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
        do{try habitContext.save()}catch{print("no save")}
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

For your information, habitArray is an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Why are you using NSMutableArray instead of Array when programming in swift? Are you sure your issue isn’t somewhere else in your code?

Comment: it is a bit old project. I will refactor the code later on, but now I just want to fix this bug. what would you prefer insted of NSMutableArray for storing the core data objects. I don't use entity class. That's why I use this.